# Polymer How to get integer value of paper-dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I am using Polymer's paper dropdown menu in my application and it has a list of integers as paper-items. 
I am trying to extract the selected value from the dropdown, but I always get this error :

Type Error : Undefined is not an object.

The code I am using is this :

```
<paper-dropdown-menu id="dropmenu" label="Select Here&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;">
        <paper-dropdown class="dropdown">
          <core-menu class="menu">
              <paper-item>0.405</paper-item>
              <paper-item>0.540</paper-item>
```

and so on..

and for JS :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function getDropdownVal()
  {
  var f = function()
  {
      var dropd = document.querySelector('#dropmenu').detail.item;
      var x = dropd.value;
      var y = parseInt(x);
      alert("Selected item is" +y);
  };
  f();
};
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong ? How do I fix this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

has an **selectedItemLabel** property which gives you the label of the selected item.

You can simply parse it using javascript.

```
var selectedItem = document.querySelector('paper-dropdown-menu').selectedItemLabel;

var result= parseInt(selectedItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, items belongs to core-menu:

```
<core-menu id="menu" class="menu">
  <paper-item>0.405</paper-item>
  <paper-item>0.540</paper-item>
  <!-- other items -->
</core-menu>
```

If you need to get selected item from outer code, try this one:

```
var selected_item = document.querySelector('#menu').selectedItem;
if (selected_item) {
  alert("Selected item is " + selected_item.textContent);
} else {
  alert("Item is not selected yet");
}
```